# Hibernate DetachedQuery and Spring's HibernateTemplate with Restriction giving wrong results

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm, criteria

My data structure is like this

```
Department  
     -> Employees    
        -> Gender  
        -> CityID -> Cities  
                          ->CityID  
                          ->CountryID -> Countries   
                                           -> CountryID
```

Department Class:

```
public class Department {  
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "departmentid", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>();  
}
```

I build Crteria like this:

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Department.class);       
DetachedCriteria detlCrit = criteria.createCriteria("employees");
 detlCrit.add(Restrictions.eq("gender", "MALE"));  
 detlCrit.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

I have 1 Department, 2 Employees in the Tables (1 male, 1 female).
**When I excecute this criteria iam expecting Hibernate build one 'Department'** **object, one 'Employee' object, and city, country etc.,**

**But what iam getting is 1 Department, 2 Employees.**

When I see the queries executed by Hibernate in logs, it shows two queries
First Query:

```
Select * from Department, Employee  
     Left outer join City on Employee.cityID = City.cityID  
     Left outer join Country on City.countryID = City.countryID  
     Where Employee.DeptID = Department.DeptID  
      AND  Employee.Gender = 'MALE';
```

Second query:

```
Select * from Employee  
     Left outer join City on Employee.cityID = City.cityID  
     Left outer join Country on City.countryID = City.countryID  
     Where Employee.DeptID = Department.DeptID;
```

Second query is wrong there is no Restriction applied on Gender='MALE';

What iam doing wrong? any suggestions? how to solve this?

sorry queries may be not exactly correct, but you got the idea.
Any more details needed please ask, I can provide.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Could you please share the code which uses the `DetachedCriteria` to execute the querries.

Comment: When you say two employee objects are returned, you mean two MALE objects; or a MALE and FEMALE?

Comment: @Mithun, MALE and FEMALE two records. Restriction failed. iam expecting only MALE Employee record.

Comment: if I changed to use HQL with getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedParam(query, params, values), it works, not getting unwanted Employee records (and it execute one sql query not two). how to make it to work using Criteria?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,using SessionFactory.

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Department.class);

criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("gender", "MALE"));
```

Hope I was useful.

Comment: @OneToMany(mappedBy = "departmentid", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>();

Comment: @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
@JoinColumn(name = "DepartmentId")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private Set<Employee>  = new HashSet<>();

Comment: Thank  you for looking into my question.
First thing 'Gender' is the field in Employee (child) table so added Restriction like this:  

`DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Department.class);`       
`DetachedCriteria detlCrit = criteria.createCriteria("employees");` 
 detlCrit.add(Restrictions.eq("gender", "MALE"));  

Department class have :  

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "departmentid", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)  
 private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>();  

Second :  I want use DetachedCriteria not the Criteria.

Comment: I cannot use SessionFactory, because I am using org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate as a standard in the project.

Comment: You can use SessionFactory as a Constructor in org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate like HibernateTemplate(SessionFactory sessionFactory) and then create a new HibernateTemplate instance.

Answer (score 1):

The first query is selecting `Department` entities and the filtering is applied as you specified in your where clause.

But you cannot truncate associations, you always have to fetch them all eagerly or lazily. That's because Hibernate has to maintain consistency guarantees when [flushing back](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpahibernate-flush-strategies/) the loaded Department entity and possibly [cascading](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/) the employees state back to the database.

The second query is most likely because you use a [FetchType.EAGER](http://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/) on your employees collection:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "department", orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
```

Once the Department is fetched, the employee collection is fetched eagerly as well.

Try with an HQL query liken this one:

```
select distinct d
from Department d
left join fetch d.employees e
where e.gender = :gender
```

Comment: I tried both orphanRemoval and changing to FetchType.LAZY still not solved. When I use LAZY initialization I am getting error `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: xxxx.employees, no session or session was closed`

Comment: but I don't want use HQL unless absolutely necessary because I am using Criterias as a standard in the project.

Comment: Try it first and see if it solves the problem, then we can turn it into a Criteria too.

Comment: Ok I tried with HQL with getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedParam(query, params, values), it works. Now I am not getting unwanted records (and it execute one sql query not two). But what is the wrong with getHibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(), how to make it to work?